swupdate and target image size
I try to use swupdate to update my system. My swu file is pretty simple
software =                                                                      
{                                                                               
        version = "0.1";
        hardware-compatibility: [ "1.0" ];                                                        

        images: (                                                               
                {                                                               
                        filename = "rfs.img.tar.gz";                            
                        device = "/dev/mmcblk1_rfs_nonative";                      
                        type = "raw";                                           
                        sha256 = "SHA";
                        compressed = true;      
                        installed-directly = true; 
                }                                                               
        );                                                                      
} 

The rfs.img.tar.gz archive contains rfs.img image
$ ls -la rfs.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexhoppus alexhoppus 2147483648 May  3 16:51 rfs.img

on my system target partition has following properties
/dev/mmcblk1p2       4202496  8396799 4194304    2G 83 Linux

You can see that size of the partition is exactly the same as image size
>>> 4194304*512
2147483648

however when I try to update, swupdate gives me the following error:
2147483648[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR : cannot write 8192 bytes: No space left on device
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [install_single_image] : Installer for raw not successful !
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR : Error streaming rfs.img.tar.gz
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [1] Image invalid or corrupted. Not installing ...
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_initializer] : Main thread sleep again !
[INFO ] : No SWUPDATE running :  Waiting for requests...
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR : SWUpdate *failed* !

if I reduce image size a little bit (8K) it works. However, I don't understand what is the problem with fitting original image into the partition.
